# PHP regular expression with a specific word _my_separator_

Tags: php, regex

Please I have I want to use regex to preg_match this kind of string :

```
$liste = 'bla0bla-__my_separator_-01blabla';
```

I've tried :

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]_my_separator_[a-zA-Z0-9]$/', $liste))
     echo 'ok';
else echo 'not ok';
```

But this returns always **not ok**.

Please masters any advise ?

PS : I think that the problem is the **_** and the **-** that what I've tried does not support !

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your regex pattern to this:

```
'/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+?_my_separator_[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+?$/'
```

Comment: This would work. Note that you don't need to escape the hyphen when it is the last character inside the character class, but it won't hurt either.

Comment: @StephenBooher Thanks for the heads up. :) I am generally wary of special/control characters in regular expressions and I prefer to escape them if they are to be used as-is even for cases as you pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

If you're only trying to determine if a **static** substring exists in a string you should use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
if (strpos('_my_separator_', $liste) !== false) {
  echo 'ok';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the repeater `+` and `-` and `_` in your whitelists:

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+_my_separator_[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+$/`

Your orignal regex would match things like:

```
A_my_seperator_B
0_my_seperator_C
```

but not:

```
AB_my_seperator_C
```

Comment: The original string has `-__` before `my` and `_-` after `separator`.

Comment: the first and last `_` are part of separator it seems.